# Fcurve noise modifier: change settings with python

Tags: python, animation, modifiers

I have a noise modifier on a scaling action on a cube. I want to adjust the scale, strength and phase settings of the modifier, for all three axes of the action, with python.

I can add the modifier:

```
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Scaling')
bpy.context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
bpy.ops.graph.fmodifier_add(type='NOISE')
```

but I can't figure out how to access the modifier settings for scale, strength and phase.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. I removed [solved] from the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't ever use `bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu()`, it's solely meant for user interface interaction. Use `Object.keyframe_insert()` (not the operator!) instead.

There's also no reason to use `bpy.ops.graph.fmodifier_add()`, especially because the dependency on an area type. Use the low-level RNA methods instead:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object

ob.keyframe_insert("scale") # ensures animation_data and action are not None
action = ob.animation_data.action

for fcu in action.fcurves:
    if fcu.data_path == "scale":
        mod = fcu.modifiers.new("NOISE")
        mod.scale = 5
```